# On cohomology ring of a mapping cone .

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let $\eta: S^{3} \rightarrow S^{2}$ be the Hopf map, that is, the attaching map for $C P^{2}$. Consider the map $\tau$ expressed as the composite
$$
\tau: S^{3} \rightarrow S^{3} \vee S^{3 \stackrel{\eta \vee \eta}{\rightarrow}} S^{2} \vee S^{2},
$$
where the map $S^{3} \rightarrow S^{3} \vee S^{3}$ is the map obtained by pinching the equatorial $S^{2}$ to a point. Let $P$ be the mapping cone of $\tau$.

a) Let $r_{1}: S^{2} \vee S^{2} \rightarrow S^{2}$ be the map which quotients out the second factor. Prove that $r_{1} \circ \tau$ of is homotopic to
$\eta$. Using this produce a map $P \rightarrow \mathbb{C} P^{2}$ which induces the identity map on $H^{4}$.

b) By constructing maps similar to the one in a), compute the ring structure on $H^{*}(P)$.

c) Is $P \simeq S^{2} \times S^{2}$ ?

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$
I couldn't solve $6b.$
I have attached a picture of what I have tried. At last, I couldn't find the cup product of $(\alpha,0)$ with $(0,\beta) ?$ Thanks in advance for any help .
[image]

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: I couldn't get what you meant .

Comment: Type up your work; don't just upload a picture of it. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/104041).

Comment: @Shaun I'd suggest you also give an example of how to draw diagrams then, the OP may not be familiar (neither am I)

Comment: That's a fair point, @Ilya. Pictures of diagrams are fine.